# Artifactory allow anonymous access for docker pull

Tags: authentication, docker, permissions, artifactory

I have set anonymous access enabled for the read operations in the docker. But when I try to pull an image from the repository it asks for an authentication password.

What is the correct way to set anonymous read access to the docker repository ? I have followed this documentation

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions

Following is the error

Error response from daemon: Get https://my-repo/v2/nginx/manifests/latest: unknown: Unauthorized

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  I am running into a similar problem.

Comment: I had to upgrade artifactory, it was something they fixed in the later versions , 4.13 I think, worth checking release notes